# Remotely hosting and executing WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, api, soap

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme for a company, and I'd like to keep some of the source code private (the client is okay with this).

The theme only contains a handful of code that I'd like to protect. (The vast majority of the theme is constructed like any other WP theme --nothing to hide.)

I have considered encrypting some of this source code in question with something like ionCube, but I'd rather not go that route, unless of course it's the only route that I can realistically go.

My question is, is there a way that I can host these source files on my server, and remotely send the theme data to their WordPress installation, perhaps via another plugin or API? My goal is to ensure that only I have access to certain parts of the source code.

I really have no idea where to begin with something like this, so I am open to all suggestions. I've tagged the post with a few different tags that I think may be relevant.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: what is returned by the 'private' part of theme?

Comment: Hey Dagon, just some custom (PHP) code that I'd like to keep under wraps, nothing malicious. As to why I want to keep it private, this company's WP install has been hacked a few times in the past, and I want to protect my code.

Comment: returning code from a remote server is a bad idea, you have to use the likes of eval() to run it, can you return output instead?

Comment: I think this is difficult if the files are on a different server.

Comment: Anything your client's webserver can access, the client can access, as well. If your private PHP code can be executed on your own server, you can just pass the resulting HTML/Javascript/whatever to your client's server instead of executing it there. Just install wordpress on your server, as well.

Comment: also as great as your code may be, its unlikely to be world shatteringly unique, sure you don't want it ripped off, but considering how many billions of line of code are in the public domain,  i think you could live with losing yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this you have two solutions:

1st: Host the entire site, then nobody will be able to access to the code.

2nd: Serve the "private" content from your own server, you can do it with javascript (aka Ajax), or with PHP curl. You can even go through a html5 web socket.

Nevertheless, remember that when you create a work for someone, that code is for them ... and hiding code this way is not well seen.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks V, the thing is, I need to remotely grab actual PHP code, not the output.

Comment: Well, then you can just make a request to send your raw code, and then execute it. But that's extremely unsafe, as you'll be evaluating and executing code from other machine, so if someone attacks to that connection and changes that code, he/she might break your entire system.

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that WordPress is GPL right? This also applies to any themes,  which means any php or html code that intermingles with WordPress code is also subject to GPL. You might very well be jeopardizing your relationship with the client by not understanding how the licensing of open source works.

It is not only hard to imagine a case of somehow creating a theme that interacts with WordPress without breaking the license terms, but why anyone one would want to do this for a legitimate or a professional reason.

http://drupal.org/licensing/faq/
http://wordpress.org/news/2009/07/themes-are-gpl-too/